# String length limit exceeded when escaped

Tags: c#, .net, xml, text, escaping

Text is introduced into the system, it can be ANYTHING, it has to be stored on a database as text (length limit here) and it has to be escaped to be XML safe.

In this case (with 6 as length limit):

```
string theInput = "hell&";
```

It would be escaped to

```
"hell&amp;"
```

And then saved to (truncation by)

```
"hell&a"
```

Now the problem is that I was assuming that the input was well escaped, when it's not.

In this case the desired output would be "hell", since I'm not interested in saving something whose escaped output can't be stored properly.

Is there a built-in function to achieve this? (.NET framework 4), like;

```
SecurityElement.Escape(text, maxLen); //this overload does not exist :(
```

If not, suggestions?

EDIT: Just to clarify; the input must be stored XML-Safe (on the DB) since other parts of the system need it that way (including not easy to update clients)

Comment: I would consider a different approach. One possibility: just store what the user enters. Perform your escaping when you retrieve the data prior to displaying it. If you must escape your text before storing it, write a CustomValidator, perform the escape as part of validating the input and fail validation if the resulting string is too long.

Comment: Is there a built-in function to achieve this? No. any more question?

Comment: @L.B "If not, suggestions?"

Comment: @BobKaufman The input can't be rejected because of the escaped result being too long, it comes from many clients that won't move a finger to correct it

Comment: @BobKaufman has it right. Do this at the time of XML serialization, not database storage. The database shouldn't know or care how you use the text anyway.

Comment: when the input is retrieved from the database it has to be valid

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in that achieves what you want. What you'll have to do is escaping the full string and THEN check for the length. If it exceeds the maximum, you'll have to check if the char at the max index falls between an & and a ;. If it does, further analysis will need to be made.

Comment: I have a piece of code that deals with the problem (basically searchs for a bad formed escape code at the end), but it is not covering all the possible results, and since it will be running millions of times per hour in certain scenarios, I was looking for something widely used and tested

Comment: I'm afraid there's no other answer, unfortunately. You might want to cover possibilities as they come so that in the middle to long term your code will cover most if not all of them.